# ImportError: No module named pyopengv

Tags: python, pip

[image]

Hi, I am having problem using openSFM. My first time....

I tried the command

```sh
bin/opensfm_run_all data/berlin
```

and the error comes out like this:

```sh
Running using Python command: python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/bin/opensfm", line 10, in <module>
    from opensfm import commands
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import match_features
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/match_features.py", line 9, in <module>
    from opensfm import matching
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/matching.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyopengv
ImportError: No module named pyopengv
```

It seems like pyopengv is not installed so I tried the

```sh
pip install opengv and pip3 install opengv
```

but then another problem comes out...

```sh
Collecting opengv
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/opengv/
```

Can anyone give me solution, please? Thanks is advance!!

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's some helpful information for you: https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/issues/366

Comment: Thanks. It saids that i need to redo the path by using this command >> cmake ../opengv -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/     but i don't know where to use it.

Comment: I followed the instruction but still the opengv is not in the  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages ..    any idea how to manually add the lib     pyopengv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so       in the /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages ????  pyopengv is builted but still not in the python3 package

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `opengv` library in PyPi repository, you have to install it manually as explained here: http://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/page_installation.html

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libeigen3-dev
git clone https://github.com/laurentkneip/opengv
cd opengv
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

Comment: I followed the installation but still does not work. The same error comes out.  If i use pip3 list or pip list ,  there is no opengv.

Comment: Don't forget to set `-DBUILD_PYTHON=ON` as mentioned in the guide linked in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is an environment error. it is likely that opengv for python V3 has been installed into the python V2 folder. Please try using opengv's cmake option

```
cmake ../opengv -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
```

Comment: Where should i use the command?? I tried the command but it still does not work. Same error comes out.

Comment: If i use pip3 list or pip list ,  there is no opengv.

Comment: check this link a guide for installation https://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/page_installation.html

Comment: I followed the instruction but still the opengv is not in the  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages ..    any idea how to manually add the lib     pyopengv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so       in the /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages ????

Comment: This is code isn't very clear in where the problem lies no errors as to why it hasn't worked, when you create your build directory and cd into it, Run `ccmake ../` to see how everything is linking, fairly sure something isn't right in there. I'm having a load of issues getting it to reference boost properly. In the doc's, boost is essential when building the python module.